# Are "If I could" clauses always followed by "would"?

Tags: conditionals, would, protasis

I always see

> If I could ... I would.

For example,

> If I could speak English, I would go to English-speaking countries.

Is there a rule against a conditional clause which contains *could*, being followed by another *could* in the main clause?

For example,

> If I could speak German, I could understand this essay.

I am a native American speaker but I do not know if the above is actually wrong.

Comment: Having the ability to do something not only allows you to do things you otherwise wouldn’t, it gives the possibility to do things that otherwise wouldn’t exist- of course you don’t always do those things just because you can. If I could understand German I ***could*** get a job in Germany, but I probably wouldn’t.

Comment: There is no rule against it, but repeating words in a sentence is generally not recommended.

Comment: Not essential. *If cars could fly, goodness knows how many accidents might arise*.

Comment: No. *If I could dance, I might go dancing*

Answer (score 3):

"If I could then I would" and "if I could then I could" are both valid but have slightly different meanings.  "If I could then I would" means if I were able to do something the I would do it.  "If I could then I could" is just redundant.  It means that if I were able to do something then I would be able to do it- not that I necessarily **would** do it.

Comment: There need be some citations made from authoritative sources to make this something other than opinion.. An answer expected, rather than an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things.

> If I could speak English, I could go to New York

> If I could speak English, I would go to New York.

In all three cases, [could](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could) continues to mean

> used to express possibility, especially slight or uncertain possibility:

whereas [would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) means

> used to refer to future time from the point of view of the past:

Hence, the first means that the trip is *possible*, and the second means the trip is *certain* -- both in event of the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples are fine and correct.

*Could* merely indicates capability in this context: *I could speak English*; *cars could fly*. *If* implies a conditional clause: *if I could change the world*; *if I could have a moment of your time*.

A conditional indeed strongly implies that a prediction is about to follow: *I would make the day longer*; *I would like to propose a toast*. A prediction is a claim that some state of affairs *will* arise, so, *can* implies *will*, and *could* implies *would*. However, a prediction doesn't necessarily have to contain the word *would*, even in a contraction (*I'd like to propose a toast*). Some predictions are claims about likelihood:

> If Beth could make it to the finals, she might take the gold.

Some predictions claim another capability:

> If Archimedes could find a suitable fulcrum, he could move the earth.

Some predictions strongly imply a future event, and so the future tense of *would* enters (although technically, this uses a slightly different sense of *could*):

> If you could finish that report for me by this evening,
>   I will summarize it for our boss tomorrow morning.

In general, meaning is king; words just convey them. If the meaning calls for an implication, you would (ahem) frequently use *would*. But if another word also conveyed the meaning of an implication, it would also fit.

Comment: I changed it to the form used in the OP.